# enable curl extension for php 7 on debian 9

Tags: php, curl, testing, debian

system: Debian GNU/Linux 9.0 (stretch); php v7.0.15-1 on command line; phpversion() shows: PHP Version 5.6.24-1+b1

I've installed curl with `apt-get install php-curl`, but the curl functions are not available in php. (php-curl installs curl for php7)

```
echo 'Curl: ', function_exists('curl_version') ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled'
```

returns: "Curl: Disabled"; also when I run phpinfo() curl is not listed;

the php5 module is enabled, but there is no php5-curl or php5.6-curl package in debian 9. When I install php-7 or php-7.1 I get: 
`php5 module already enabled, not enabling PHP 7.1`

How can I disable the php5 module and enable php7 on debian9 or install php5-curl under debian 9?

cheers
Piotr

Comment: ok, I've found a solution; there is a folder called modules-enabled with symbolic links to the modules; I just removed the links to php5 and created new ones to php7;

now phpinfo() shows php7 and also the curl module

Comment: i think it's `apt-get install php7.0-curl`